# Swift Type of expression is ambiguous without more context error on Task

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a simple get request, but each time compiler tells me that there is a "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error from the line that begins with `Task`.

Researching this error seems like there are different reasons for it to appear, so I have not found this particular case with Task in the results.

This is my whole application:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Quote: Codable, Identifiable{
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var body: String
}
struct ContentView: View{
    var body: some View{
        Text("Hello").onAppear{
            let urlString = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"
            guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else{return}
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.setValue("aplication/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            let session = URLSession.shared
            Task{
                let (data, response) = try? await session.data(from: url)
            }
        }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The error appears right in this place:

```
Task{
    let (data, response) = try? await session.data(from: url)
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be the optional `try?`. Removing the question mark allowed the code to compile. However, you are not using the url request so you probably want `let (data, response) = try await session.data(for: request)`

Comment: `URLSesssion` and `URLRequest` code doesn't belong directly in the `body` they need to be in an `action` of sorts like inside the `action` of a `Button` or `.task`

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI it's `.task` not `Task`. Or `.task(id:)` if you want it to restart when a value changes that you supply as `id`.

Comment: Nope, in that context the problem was rather in using a question mark with `try`

Comment: Putting same code in .task() didn't help